# Multiple TinyMCE Instances - Unable to Use "Get" Method

Tags: tinymce

I have initiated two instances of the TinyMCE editor on the same webpage...shown below.

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '#post-content',
    placeholder: 'Type your post here...',
    elementpath: false,
    resize: false,
    plugins: '',
    toolbar: '',
    menubar: '',
});

tinymce.init({
    selector: '.post-comment-form-input',
    placeholder: 'Type your comment here...',
    elementpath: false,
    resize: false,
    height: "100",
    plugins: '',
    toolbar: '',
    menubar: '',
});
```

When I execute a command on the first instance, it all goes just fine (shown below).

```
$('btn').click(function() {
    tinyMCE.get('post-content').setContent('');
});
```

However, when I execute a command on the second instance, I get the following "Cannot read property 'setContent' of null".

```
$('btn').click(function() {
    tinyMCE.get('post-comment-form-input').setContent('');
});
```

Both TinyMCE editors show just fine on the webpage, so I know they are initializing properly. It's just when I try to use a command on that second instance it doesn't work. I have tried including a period in the 2nd function since it's a class, but that doesn't work either.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tinymce.get()` requires you to pass the **ID** of the HTML element.  Based on your `init()` sections the second selector is using a **CLASS** which is not valid for the `tinymce.get()` API.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't sure about that or not because in the article for multiple TinyMCE instances, their selector in the init() is a class instead of an ID. However, they don't focus on the .get() in that article.

Comment: If that resolved your issue can you mark the question as solved so others know this is no longer an issue?  Thanks!